# how to save user's details after logout

Tags: angular

I am setting up an authentication application with angular 7 and I want to save user's details (Firstname, Lastname, loginTime, duration of connection) in each authentication.

EmployeeDetails.ts :

```
`import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../_models';
import { UserService, AuthenticationService } from '../_services';
@Component({
selector: 'app-employee-details',
templateUrl: './employee-details.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./employee-details.component.css']
})

export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
currentUser: User;
userFromApi: User;
constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private userService: UserService
) {
        this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getById(this.currentUser.id).pipe(first()).subscribe(
data => { 
    this.userFromApi = data;
});`
```

EmployeeDetails.html :

```
`<h1>Hi {{currentUser.role}}!</h1>

<h3>users's details</h3>
<ul>
<li >
    {{currentUser.username}} ({{currentUser.firstName}} 
{{currentUser.lastName}}) <strong>start connection at 
{{authenticationService.today | date :'medium'}} </strong> duration : 
{{authenticationService.timeLeft}}

</li>
</ul>`
```

I want to see the details of all users who logged In , but I just see the detail of the current user , how can I save every time the current user's detail ?
[this is the result when i run the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Ai5.png)

Thanks for help !

Comment: You pretty far away from this. To realize something like this you need to sent the date to your backend when the server logged in and you need to track the last request from this user. Usually by his login token. So everytime he makes a server request with the token, you save it. The difference between login and last user action is your duration. You wait for "logging out", most user just closing the browser. All those things needs to be saved in a persistence, like a database.

Comment: thanks but i am using fake server json (fake backend) is it 
feasible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to use a websocket instead of the default http-connection for this scenario.
HTTP is only working with request => response, so if you dont request anything (for example when you close the browser, then your service won't know about the exact time)
A Websocket is a two-way open connection, where you get a disconnect event, even if the user closes the browsertab.

A good example is available on https://socket.io/